Editing content in multiple rows of a column
I have a column (named CATEGORY) which has 999 rows. Every row in that column has names (like culture, tradition, technology etc). Many of the rows have these names in '' or "" (like 'culture' or "technology"). I want to remove the ''/""  so that all rows have only names. I am unable to make the syntax. Kindly help
update social_buzz.content
set category = replace(category, '"culture"""', 'culture');

The problem i am facing is that the words have different no. of characters. The above syntax worked whereever the record had the word culture but I want to execute so that all words like "tradition""" become tradition, irrespective the length of words
